# How to trace the listbox size in tkinter on every insert?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I am not able to trace out the size of the list box on every insert to Listbox in Tkinter, python

Actually, I am taking data for the communication port on a while loop and adding the text output to Listbox.

Comment: Why don't you bind to `"<Configure>"`?

Comment: Do you want to get the number of items inside the listbox? If yes then try `listbox.index("end")` where `listbox` is the instance of `Listbox()`.